# This function returns a list that contains the values that appear in list "A" at positions given in "pos_list"

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list, deep-copy

-If A list has integer data such as: 1->2->3->4->5->6
-And pos_list has integer data such as: 4->0->5
-Then this function should return a New List hat contains the values that appear in list A at positions given in pos_list
such that New List=  5->1->6

I am implementing deep copy to make new List.
I am trying to use a loop that iterates according to the data of pos_list. Inside this loop, node of A will move to position of pos_list data. In this time i will copy the node A in new list to make another list. 
Say for first case, pos_list has data 4, so the loop will run 4 times until the node of list A points to its fourth position. Inside this loop i will copy the data of list A in a new loop. 
I need a guidance to solve this problem.

```
struct node * sublist(struct node * A, struct node * pos_list) {
struct node* newList=NULL;
struct node * curr;
int i=0;

for (i = 0, curr = pos_list->next; (curr != NULL); curr = curr->next) { //pos_list->data has a dummy node so loop until the end of pos_list->data.
   struct node* newList = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof (struct node));

    for(int i=0;i<=pos_list->data;i++){   //counter for pos_list as it will be (3 then 0,6 and 4)
        if(i==pos_list->data){            //At the time when i == pos_list->data(3 or 0 or 6..)
            newList->data = A->data;      //Putting value of list A data in new list.
            newList = newList->next;      //Linking
            printf("%d\t", newList->data);   //Just for log
        }
        A=A->next;                       //Going to next position on A
    }
   pos_list=pos_list->next;             //Going to next position on B
}
return newList ;
}
```

If A list is   : 1->2->3->4->5->6
And pos_list is: 4->0->5

I expect the output is new list as 5->1->6

Comment: Always check your logic with edge cases. What if you have an empty pos_list? What if you have a one-element pos_list?

Comment: This problem requires a pos_list data to arrange the new list so there is no chance of pos_list being empty. Although empty pos_list can be one of the test cases but no arrangement will be made. New list should be arranged in a way that it contains the values that appear in list A at positions given in pos_list.

Comment: An empty list is a list with zero elements. Unless your assignment specifically says "non-empty list", or there is some inherent reason for a list to be non-empty, any list is potentially empty. In this problem there is no such reason. An empty pos_list will simply result in an empty list as the result. There is nothing wrong with this whatsoever.

Comment: The posted code contains no function(s).  It is missing the definition of `struct node`

Comment: Stackoverflow is not here to write your code for you.  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: There seems to be missing any check (of each entry in the 'positions' list) to assure there are (at least) that many entries in the 'data' list

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct node* newList = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof (struct node));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing the cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `newList = newList->next;      //Linking`  this 'effectively' sets the pointer `newList` to some trash.  Amongst other reasons is because the field `next` has not been initialized to NULL.

Comment: regarding: `int i=0;` and `for (i = 0,` and `for(int i=0;`  Much better for the first `for()` to eliminate the expression: `i = 0` AND to eliminate the declaration: `int i;` as that variable is never used (although a new variable in the second `for()` statement does 'shadow'/'mask' it

Comment: in the first `for()` statement, this initialization expression: `curr = pos_list->next;` skips the first entry in the list.  Suggest: `curr = pos_list;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- You should start your traversal with `pos_list`, not with `pos_list->next`. The node pointed to by the head pointer is part of the list. Further, if `pos_list == NULL`, `pos_list->next` will lead to undefined behaviour.
- The outer definition of `int i` isn't useful. Delete it.
- Don't iterate through `A` by means of the position. If the position isn't valid, you will walk beyond the end of the list, get null pointers and invoke undefined behaviour. Lists should be iterated by list nodes accessed from the previous nodes' `next` pointers. (It is, of course, the caller's resposibility to provide valid positions, but your program should handle invalid input gracefully.)
- Create the new node only when you have found a valid position. Otherwise you create a node that is never inserted and thus leak memory.
- Here: `newList = newList->next`, `newList->next` isn't initialized. Remember that `malloc` gives you a chunk of uninitialized data.
- You try to make `newList` point to the end of the newly created list, so that appending new nodes ist fast. That's a good idea, but if you return that pointer, you'll get a list that consists only of one element. (You'll also no loger be able to access any previously created nodes in that list.)

Here's an implementation that should work:

```
struct node *sublist(struct node *A, struct node *pos_list)
{
    struct node *newHead = NULL;
    struct node *newTail = NULL;
    struct node *pos = pos_list;

    while (pos) {
        struct node *a = A;
        int i = 0;

        while (a) {
            if (i == pos->data) {
                struct node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

                if (newHead == NULL)  newHead = node;
                if (newTail) newTail->next = node;
                node->data = a->data;
                node->next = NULL;
                newTail = node;

                break;
            }

            a = a->next;
            i++;
        }

        pos = pos->next;
    }

    return newHead;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @M Oehm. Your guidance helped me. 
But i had to replace i=0 with i=-1 for the correct output order.

Comment: Do you have a dummy node at the beginning of your original list? (That would explain why you start with `pos->next`.) Don't do that. It causes more trouble than it's worth. An empty list should be represented by a head pointer that is `NULL` and it has no nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not condone using a "struct" to implement the solution.
If it does, I am mistaken but if it does not, isn't it an overkill, when something akin to the following can be implemented....

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define CREATE_ARRAY(n) int result[n]

void main() {
  int data[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  int pos[] = {4,0,5};
  int i;

  CREATE_ARRAY(sizeof(pos)/sizeof(int));
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(pos)/sizeof(int);++i)
    result[i] = data[pos[i]];
/*
  To print the values stored in result
  for(i = 0;i < sizeof(result)/sizeof(int); ++i)
    printf("%d ",result[i]);
  putchar('\n');
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `sublist` should be declared like

```
struct node * sublist( const struct node *A, const struct node *pos_list );
```

because neither the list `A` nor the list `pos_list` are changed in the function. Otherwise the declaration of the function confuses readers of the code.

It is a bad idea that the list `pos_list` contains a dummy node as it is wrote in the comment to this statement

```
for (i = 0, curr = pos_list->next; (curr != NULL); curr = curr->next) { //pos_list->data has a dummy node so loop until the end of pos_list->data
```

Neither dummy node should be in the list.

In this inner loop

```
for(int i=0;i<=pos_list->data;i++){
```

there is not used the dummy node of the list. Moreover the pos_list is traversed in the two loops: the outer loop and the inner loop

```
for (i = 0, curr = pos_list->next; (curr != NULL); curr = curr->next) { //pos_list->data has a dummy node so loop until the end of pos_list->data.
   struct node* newList = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof (struct node));

    for(int i=0;i<=pos_list->data;i++){
```

Within the loops the value of the variable `newList` is changed

```
newList = newList->next;
```

So as a result the function  always returns some indeterminate value instead of the head of the newly created list. The value is indeterminate because the data member next of a new created node is not initialized.

```
newList->data = A->data;      //Putting value of list A data in new list.
newList = newList->next;
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
struct node * sublist( const struct node *A, const struct node *pos_list ) 
{
    struct node *newList = NULL;
    struct node **current = &newList;

    for ( ; pos_list != NULL; pos_list = pos_list->next )
    {
        const struct node *target = A;

        for ( int index = pos_list->data; index != 0 && target != NULL; --index )
        {
            target = target->next;
        }

        if ( target != NULL )
        {
            *current = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
            ( *current )->data = target->data;
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    return newList;
}
```